# Why isn't my parent pom getting updated with openrewrite recipe?

Tags: openrewrite

I am using the recipe to upgrade spring boot version
https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/spring/boot3/upgradespringboot_3_0

Nothing is getting in pom.xml but I see build success and changes applied in source code files.

I do see the following message:

[WARNING] There were problems parsing some source files, run with --errors to see full stack traces
[WARNING] There were problems parsing src\test\resources\application.yml
[INFO] Running recipe(s)...
line 1:0 missing '@' at 'org'
line 1:0 missing '@' at 'org'

Comment: Is there any logging output that indicates there's a parsing error with your pom.xml file? Are you using the Spring Boot Maven parent pom.xml? I'm missing information that would help me to debug your issue.

Comment: [WARNING] There were problems parsing some source files, run with --errors to see full stack traces [WARNING] There were problems parsing src\test\resources\application.yml [INFO] Running recipe(s)... line 1:0 missing '@' at 'org' line 1:0 missing '@' at 'org'

Comment: @Tim,
Yes, using spring boot pom.
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.7</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

Comment: I encounter the same problem. @SDev: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

To help debug your issue it would be good to know what [versions of the Maven plugin](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-maven-plugin/releases) and [rewrite-spring](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-spring/releases) you used. We just did a new release of both, which might already resolve your issues. If not, please [log an issue](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-spring/issues) with more details.

As it stands there's not enough information in your question to help us debug any further.